# Why does an open IE DOM Explorer cause "Unspecified error" in JavaScript on window close?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

First: I have my server set to catch and log all client JS errors, and display an alert() anytime a runtime JS error is encountered. Ex:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onerror = function() {
    alert("Error caught");
  };
</script>
```

If a user has the DOM Explorer open in IE and closes the window, they get an "Unspecified error" alert after the window closes. There is no source file listed in the error, but it happens on every page that sources JavaScript. The client and the server both recognize the error.

This is the last error I'm getting; all the JavaScript, HTML, and CSS work/display correctly on every browser, but IE has this last issue. This happens in IE5, IE7 and IE11(Edge).

What else can I provide to help diagnose?

Edit:: Code is as follows.

```
(function(window) {
  function CatchRuntimeJSError(message, filename, lineno, colno, error) {
    Log(filename + ":" + lineno, message);
    var err = "You've had a run-time JavaScript Error.";
    alert(err); 
  }
  window.onerror = CatchRuntimeJSError;
})(window);
```

This code snippet is in "Errors.js" and is the last thing included by a page.

The handler values are as follows:

1. message: "Unspecified error"
2. filename: the URL of the page if static, blank if generated by other code via cgi.
3. lineno: 1
4. colno: 1
5. error: "Error: unspecified error."

When passing event as a parameter, event is undefined.

Comment: I'm interested in this too. I've basically figured it's harmless, but it would be good to know what's up with it.

Comment: Which version of IE? With which arguments is the event handler called? According to [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#the-event-handler-processing-algorithm) they should be message, filename, lineno, colno, error.

Comment: It is harmless, but IE's developer tools are inferior to others out there. In some versions of IE, you will get an error from JS code that references the `console`, when the developer tools are closed because the `console` object is only created when the tools are opened.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I know that was true in IE8 but I haven't seen that happen in recent versions. IE Dev Tools do have some shortcomings, like with how difficult it is to work with pseudo-elements in it compared to Chrome, but it's not particularly *bad*.

Comment: @Oriol It is happening in IE5, IE7 and IE11 (Edge) all. event and event.target both are undefined. To reference your edit, my event handler has all of them.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I think they are bad when compared to Chrome. On their own, they are, as you are seeing, quirky.

Comment: Does some parameter say something useful?

Comment: @Oriol filename has the offending page URL (every page, though). Otherwise, lineno is 1, colno is 1, message is "unspecified error", and error is "unspecified error".

Comment: So I've found that if I wrap the catch in a 1ms timeout, neither the client nor the server see a JavaScript error; it's only on an immediate unload. All of my other catches still function. This is more of a hack than a fix.

What are the consequences of wrapping the catch in a timeout that I may not be aware of?